# Params for json array in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, json, parameters

I'm new to rails,
Please check my code and tell me whats wrong with my use params, because this is how it made sense to me.
Controller:

```
def create
    user = User.find(user_params)
    order = user.purchases.new
    render json: order.errors if !order.save

    basket = params.require(:basket)
    basket.each do |b|
        i = Item.find(b[:item_id])
        render json: i.errors, status: 422 if !i
        order.purchases_items.create(item_id: i, quantity: b[:quantity])
    end

    render nothing: true, status: 201 # location: show action        
end
```

and my test file is sending

```
test "making order" do
    post "/api/users/#{@tuser.id}/orders",
        { basket: [ { item_id: '2', quantity: '5' }, 
                    { item_id: '1', quantity: '4'} ] }.to_json,
        { 'Accept' => Mime::JSON, 'Content-Type' => Mime::JSON.to_s }

    assert_response 201
    assert_equal Mime::JSON, response.content_type
end
```

Thanks,
What I basically want to do is store each array element in the array basket from params[:basket], and iterate over it.

Comment: What is exact problem you are facing?

Comment: The test is throwing this error: 1) Error:
Api::MakingOrderTest#test_making_order:
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
    app/controllers/api/order_controller.rb:18:in `create', 
    test/integration/api/orders/making_order_test.rb:10:in `block in <class:MakingOrderTest>', where line 18 is basket = params.require[:basket]

Comment: Have you got params.require(:basket) or params.require[:basket] ? Your comment says one but the question says the other

Answer (score -1):

Sometime params keys are not get converted into symbols automatically. Can u try passing string `"basket"` instead of symbol `:basket`?

Comment: def user_params
                params.require(:id)
            end